# Evaluating Factorial Using Gamma Function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

The gamma function is the function $\Gamma: \mathbb{R}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by
$$
\Gamma(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{t-1} \exp (-x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
8.1: If we use the fundamental theorem of calculus, we get $\Gamma(1)=1 .$

8.2: The gamma function has the following useful property:
$$
\forall t>0, \quad \Gamma(t+1)=t \Gamma(t)
$$
How could we show that $\Gamma(r)=(r-1) ! $  for every $r \in \mathbb{N}$ using  Exercise 8.1 and (8.2)

Comment: By induction, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Nothe that  if $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$, with $\Gamma(1)=1$ then if $z$ is a positive integer we have, $$\Gamma(n)=\Gamma((n-1)+1)=(n-1)\Gamma(n-1)=(n-1)\Gamma((n-2)+1)=\ldots =(n-1)!$$

Comment: yes, I understand. Thanks a lot.